# Perl - Capture sentences with occurrence of more than1 element of an array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a text file and a array which has a list of words. I need to find a way where I can filter out the sentences with occurrence of more than 1 . I am just not able to formulate how to write the code. Here is an example :

Input :

```
my @strings = (
    "i'm going to find the occurrence of two words if possible",
    "i'm going to find the occurrence of two words if possible",
    "to find a solution to this problem",
    "i will try my best for a way to this problem"
);

my @words = ("find", "two", "way");
```

Output :

```
i'm going to find the occurrence of two words if possible
i'm going to find the occurrence of two words if possible
```

And I do understand it's a simple problem but my mind seems to have hit a road block.

Comment: Should it match `find find`?

Comment: Ideally it should match 'find' and 'two' but  'find' and 'find' would also be plausible.

Comment: It's a yes or no kind of question...

Comment: Yes si the answer then

Comment: Then you want strings with two or more instances of the keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want strings with two or more instances of the keywords:

```
my @keywords = ("find", "two", "way");
my %keywords = map { $_ => 1 } @keywords;

for my $string (@strings) {
   my @words = $string =~ /\w+/g;
   my $count = grep { $keywords{$_} } @words;   # Count words that are keywords.
   if ($count >= 2) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Short-circuiting alternate (i.e. good for extremely long strings):

```
my @keywords = ("find", "two", "way");
my %keywords = map { $_ => 1 } @keywords;

for my $string (@strings) {
   my $count = 0;
   while ($string =~ /\w+/g) {
      if ($keywords{$_} && ++$count == 2) {
         ...
         last;
      }
   }
}
```

---

If you want strings with instances of two or more keywords:

```
my @keywords = ("find", "two", "way");

for my $string (@strings) {
   my @words = $string =~ /\w+/g;
   my %seen; ++$seen{$_} for @words;
   my $count = grep { $seen{$_} } @keywords;   # Count keywords that were seen.
   if ($count >= 2) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Alternate:

```
my @keywords = ("find", "two", "way");

for my $string (@strings) {
   my @words = $string =~ /\w+/g;
   my %seen = map { $_ => -1 } @keywords;
   my $count = grep { ++$seen{$_} == 0 } @words;
   if ($count >= 2) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Short-circuiting alternate (i.e. good for extremely long strings):

```
my @keywords = ("find", "two", "way");

for my $string (@strings) {
   my $count = 0;
   my %seen = map { $_ => -1 } @keywords;
   while ($string =~ /\w+/g) {
      if (++$seen{$_} == 0 && ++$count == 2) {
         ...
         last;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok One more query can I use the tags \Q and \E because in my array there might be phrases which need to be matched too.

Comment: Am asking because I would have to escape special characters So hence the query.

Comment: I don't see how that answers my question. I presume you're not asking about your ability to use `\Q` and `\E`, and I presume you're not asking if it's possible to use `\Q` and `\E` (seeing as it's possible to use them in every program), so I presume that you are asking if you *should* use `\Q` and `\E`, and that would be entirely dependent on how you plan to use them.

Comment: OK i don't know where to place them but my array will have also strings like 'I am' or 'May not' or 'to-be' .Right now to match sentences having elements from my array i use :  if ( any { $line =~ /\Q$_\E/ } @names ) {
          print ...
      }